# Exception when replacing brackets

Tags: java, replace

Hey I want to replace a random letter (only the first) with an underscore. For that I use following line:

```
String newSubstring=substring.replaceFirst(randomLetter,"_");
```

That works fine except when there is a bracket "(" or ")". Then I get the following exception:

```
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466): Process: com.clozegenerator, PID: 12466
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:     Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern near index 1:
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466): )
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):  ^
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:411)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:394)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:381)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at java.lang.String.replaceFirst(String.java:1804)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at com.clozegenerator.MainActivity.generateCloze(MainActivity.java:138)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at com.clozegenerator.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:113)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18673)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
06-14 15:29:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas how I can solve that?

Comment: What is the patten? (your randomLetter)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`replaceFirst` uses regex as first parameter and in regex `(` and `)` are special (they open and close [groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) for instance) so you need to escape them using for instance `\\(` or surrounding them with `\\Q` `\\E` which represents quotation.

But to avoid escaping them manually you can use `Pattern.quote` method like

```
String newSubstring=substring.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(randomLetter),"_");
```